# Why this sprintf statement crashing?

Tags: c++, format

```
char filebuf[256];
path current = current_path();
std::cout<<"CurrentWorking "<<current<<endl;
string _UserDir = "TTiTraceLogs";
sprintf(filebuf,"%s/%s",current,_UserDir); ///crashing here
```

If I format only `current`, then it is ok.

```
sprintf(filebuf,"%s",current);
```

Output:

```
CurrentWorking D:/working/eclipse_projects/sadftp/CollectTTiTraceSept10_1009_174
_higher/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Release
```

Comment: C++ or C? Pick one, and remove the tag for the other one.

Comment: @tomalak He shouldn't remove both tags because this does appear to be a C++ to C clash where things are not working as expected. std::cout along with << overriding for the Current object is clearly C++, but it does not work nicely with the C function lower in the code... which is what the answers below touch upon.

Comment: James: If he is using a C++ compiler, then it's not a "C function". `sprintf` is part of C++, too.

Answer (score 17):

In the standard `sprintf()` function (and the other `printf()`-like functions), the `%s` specifier doesn't work with C++ `strings`s; it only works with C-style strings. Try `_UserDir.c_str()`, which gives you a `const char *` that points to the internal array of the `string` and can therefore be used with many C functions.

If `current_path()` returns something that is not a (possibly `const`) pointer to `char` or `unsigned char`, you need to convert that value too.

Comment: Haha, +1 for oldest post with the most correct statement :)

Comment: That's still going to crash though, since `sprintf()` doesn't support boost filesystem paths as well. And I might be nitpicking, but it's not the `%s` syntax which doesn't support C++ strings (it supports them perfectly well if you're using with boost::format), it's just the f-line of C library functions (scanf, printf, sprintf, vsprintf, etc.) that doesn't support it.

Comment: @Boaz Yaniv: Since I'm a nitpicker too, I've edited my answer in accordance with your comment. :-)

Comment: That's great, but you don't have to wonder about current_path() it returns a boost::filesystem::path, and IIRC, it has a c_str() method, just like std::string.

Answer (score 3):

Is `string` actually `std::string`? And `path` a `boost::filesystem::path`? In that case, you should know that C library functions (like `sprintf` and `printf`) don't support C++ classes like `std::string`. That's only natural.

What you need to do is:

```
sprintf(filebuf, "%s%s", current.c_str(), _UserDir.c_str());
```

But a more elegant solution, if you're already using C++, is to either use `std::stringstream` or `boost::format`. As a bonus won't have to mess with allocating buffers on the stack and worrying that the result might be longer than the buffer (which may lead to buffer overruns and security exploits - `sprintf()` is probably the culprit behind many of those...).

**std::stringstream**

```
std::stringstream filebuf;
filebuf << current_path().c_str() << _UserDir;
std::string filename = filebuf.str();
```

**boost::format**

```
std::string filename = "%s%s" % current_path().c_str() % _UserDir;
```

By the way, if you just want to concatenate directories, the 'proper' way to do that with `boost::filesystem::path` would be:

```
boost::filesystem::path fullPath = current_path() / _UserDir;
```

Yes, the `/` operator is used for adding path components. They are separated by slashes after all, aren't they?

That being said, if you still choose, against all good advice, to use the old C library functions, please, for all that's good in the world, don't use `sprintf()`. Use the slightly-safer [snprintf()](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/c/snprintf), which takes the maximum buffer size as an argument.

Comment: You can disagree with the correct course of action OP should take, but this answer accurately reflects why `sprintf` is crashing.

Comment: @chomp: Read the rest of my answer. It was sent prematurely.

Comment: Thanks all for taking times to advise. Yaniv, I will go either one your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your code is unclear (*e.g.*, what on earth is a `path` type?), but it looks like you're trying to print a `std::string` via a C-style string formatter (`sprintf %s`), which is totally invalid.

Look at `std::stringstream`.  Also, for simple concatenation, `std::string` provides a `+` operator overload.  So you could be doing simply:

```
current + "/" + whatever
```

Comment: I think I am going to use stringstream instead of sprintf for this boost::filesystem case

Answer (score 1):

sprintf only works with char*, you cannot use it with strings. Try _UserDir.c_str() and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

What I don't understand is why your compiler doesn't complain.  You can't pass non-POD types like `std::string` or `boost::filepath` as varargs; my compiler says that this will abort at runtime, and any compiler will know here that you're passing class types to a vararg.  (Formally, it's undefined behavior, but unless the compiler defines it somehow as an extention, then there's no reason for it not to at least warn.)

Answer (score 0):

current is not a char* pointer, it is a path so it might lead to complication

also, sprintf can't print to string variables like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

How long is `current_path`? Maybe `strlen(current_path)+strlen(_UserDir)+2 > 256`.

Comment: That's a good point, though from the `std::cout` example, his full output should only be 126 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since `_UserDir` is a C++ `string`, you'll need to get its C string to call `sprintf()`, which is a C function.

```
sprintf(filebuf,"%s/%s",current,_UserDir.c_str());  // gets C string
```

Also, what is a `path`? If it isn't like a `typedef` for `char*`, then you can't just `sprintf()` that either. It may be that `operator<<()` is overloaded for `path`, which is why the `std::cout` works.

Comment: I had tried those c_str(), still crashing. Something wrong with "path".  I can do sprintf(filebuf,"%s",current) it is working ok. The length of the path is not a problem. I will be back, I need to go lunch. Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` indicates a C string. You have a C++ string. You need to call `.c_str()`

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the crash has already been explained - I can only add one piece of advice - just ditch sprintf if possible and use string streams. It will make your code better. You will not have to worry about the length of the buffer or other errors like the one you encountered.